# Is there a way to run an optimization on an array where contiguous elements can be affected by one another?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

Suppose I have a 4 x 4 array, where every element $a_{mn}$ has a value ranging from 1 to $\phi$:

$$
 \begin{matrix}
    5 & 127 & \frac{1}{2} & 11\\
    1 & 201 & 447 & \phi - 100\\
    \phi-63 & 29 & 53 & \phi\\
    1 & 43 & 591 & 3\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I have no idea of the proper mathematics from here onwards (or even if it proper to express this as a mathematical problem), so bear with me with the lack of rigour of my language. Suppose some action $A(x)$ which takes as its argument an element $a_{mn}$ of the array is such that $A(a_{mn})$ means: multiply all neighboring elements by $\frac{1}{a_{mn}}$.

I am interesting in doing optimization problems related to such an array, or to try to find some analytical characteristics of such an array.  I am mostly looking for an excuse to learn more complicated maths, and this problem in particular interests me.

Is there any way I can find things like: what is the fastest way to get the entire array in the state such that the total sum of all elements of the array is lesser than some number $\alpha$? Or do this under the condition that some column must be optimized first? Or do this while restricting $A(x)$ to only be able to affect the right-side neighbor, or maybe do optimizations involving an $A(x)$ which multiplies neighbors, or which affects them with +1 or -1?

I was thinking that maybe an array wasn't the best form to express this mathematically, so that perhaps a 3D object could work better, and imagine A(x) as another 3D object somehow affecting the first one, but really I don't know. If someone has a particular area of mathematics to recommend that could help me model this, that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I doubt there’s a way to generalize all this. It would depend on the elements of the array, $\alpha$ etc.

Comment: @Tavish hm, would you think there could be something done if the elements of the array have some form of symmetry? At this point I'm mostly looking to find a way to formalize this problem.

Comment: Well yes. If all the elements are equal and $\alpha \gt 1$then performing $A(x)$ on an element means turning all its neighbors to 1. To minimize the number of runs, we want to centralize and spread as much as possible. For a $4\times 4$ array, this would require 4 runs on $a_{22},a_{23},a_{32},a_{33}$.